# Adding custom fonts to my iphone application

Tags: objective-c, ios4, fonts

I want to use a custom font in my iPhone app. After doing some research I found that you can add a custom font to your package. So I copied the font, which is `digreadout2.ttf` to my app folder and added a key in the .plist file. using the exact filename including the extension.

I then create the `UIFont` object and assign it to the font property of my `UILabel`. Now the problem is that when I run my app it gives me an error saying  `<Error>: FT_Open_Face failed: error 2.`

If anyone has any suggestions of what I can try it will be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the response, I found the error. Basically what happened was that the file I used for my font had a white space in the file name. So when I tried to load it in the plist file it gave the error of file not found, once I removed the space out of the filename everything worked perfecty.

Answer (score 0):

Error 2 in Free Type is `FT_ERR_BADLABEL` which *I guess* is the same as `ENOENT - No such file or directory`. Maybe you are using UIFont with the filename instead the font name. See [Certain fonts not showing up?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5941601/certain-fonts-not-showing-up/5941709#5941709)