# Bold `<b>` tag and Italic `<i>` tag not applied for custom font family

Tags: html, css, objective-c, iphone, nsattributedstring

I got below `html` string with `<b>` and `<i>` tags.

```
inputString = @"<b> Sample bold text </b> Normal Text <i> sample italic </i>";
```

*And below method will return attributed text for input html string.*

```
+(NSAttributedString *) returnRichTextForString:(NSString *) inputString {

  NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[inputString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]  options:@{   
        NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute:  NSHTMLTextDocumentType,
        NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: @(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
      }
  documentAttributes:nil
  error:nil];

   return attributedString;
}
```

Then  **custom font size, family** and pass it into above method.

```
NSString * strigAfterFontWrapper =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<style type='text/css'> body {font-size: %fpx}</style><font face='%@'>%@</font>", fontSize , customFontFamily, inputString];

label.numberOfLines = 0;

NSAttributedString *attributedstring = [NTUtilities returnRichTextForString:strigAfterFontWrapper];

label.attributedText = attributedstring;
```

But, `<b>` and `<i>` are not applied on the label!

> It works fine with default system font! Any clue why it fails in the
>   case of custom fonts ? What should I include to get `bold` or `italic`
>   ?

Comment: what happens when you don't wrap the CSS.. Is it working fine with system font?

Comment: What does looks like `strigAfterFontWrapper`? Note that the HTML to NSAttributedString method doesn't manage all HTML code.

Comment: `stringAfterFontWrapper` for example it looks like this `<style type='text/css'> body {font-size: 19.000000px}</style><font face='Comfortaa'> Normal string example.<b>Bold string sample.</b><i>Italic String example.</font>`

Comment: @GaneshSomani : Your are right dude, it works fine with System fonts ( default) used. But not working with custom fonts which are uploaded with project. I was totally forgot to try with System font ! . Thanks for noticing me :-)

Comment: @GaneshSomani : Few of custom fonts I used in my project are `BankGothic Bold, Eccentric, Rochester Regular..`

Comment: I will just write that as an answer, maybe you can accept it :)

Comment: Sure, but it will more helpful if you share solution for the case of custom font. How can I apply bold/italic ?

Comment: Did my solution work for you? If yes, maybe you can accept the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved this problem with my own hack. Before jumping to solution, I clarified effects of newly added custom fonts in iOS.  That is, if that font family comes with ready made Bold / Italic etc attributes, it will cause above problem. If not, you will face such problems.

*Solution :*

In `+(NSAttributedString *) returnRichTextForString:(NSString *) inputString` method, added below lines to overwrite existing NSAttributedString attributes.

```
[attributedString beginEditing];

[attributedString enumerateAttribute:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName inRange:NSMakeRange(0, attributedString.length) options:0 usingBlock:^(id value, NSRange range, BOOL *stop) {
    if (value) {
        NSMutableParagraphStyle *myStyle = (NSMutableParagraphStyle *)value;
        //Hack for bold effect to custom fonts
        if (myStyle.minimumLineHeight == 101) {
            [myStyle setMinimumLineHeight:0];
            [attributedString addAttribute:NSStrokeWidthAttributeName
                                     value:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:-3.0] range:range];
        }
        //Hack for italic/skew effect to custom fonts
        if (myStyle.minimumLineHeight == 99) {
            [myStyle setMinimumLineHeight:0];
            [attributedString addAttribute:NSObliquenessAttributeName
                                     value:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.30] range:range];
        }

    }
}];

[attributedString endEditing];
```

Below updates for the markup in `inputString`

```
<style type='text/css'> b { line-height:101px;} i {line-height:99px;} </style>
```

Hence, final mark up after upending above lines,

```
inputString = @"<b> Sample bold text </b> Normal Text <i> sample italic </i><style type='text/css'> b { line-height:101px;} i {line-height:99px;} </style>";
```

Here,

> Trick is to identify bold and italic tags based on `line-height`
>   value in html and comparing it with `minimumLineHeight` attribute of
>   paragraph style.  i.e for example if line-height 101 then it will be
>   bold and 99 then consider it as italic.

**UPDATE :**
This fails when  and  both are applied at the same text. To overcome this problem, Here I shared slightly modified logic. Keeping same logic to identify italic and for bold I added below lines before end editing attributes of NSAttributedstring ,

```
//Hack for bold effect.
[attributedString enumerateAttribute:NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName inRange:NSMakeRange(0, attributedString.length) options:0 usingBlock:^(id value, NSRange range, BOOL *stop) {

    if (value) {

        [attributedString addAttribute:NSStrokeWidthAttributeName
                                                 value:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:-3.0] range:range];

        [attributedString addAttribute:NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName
                                 value:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0] range:range];
    }

}];
```

and in html,

```
 b { text-decoration:line-through;}
```

My complete method is here below :

```
  +(NSAttributedString *) returnRichTextForString:(NSString *) inputString {

  NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[inputString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]  options:@{
                                                                                                                                                                 NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute:  NSHTMLTextDocumentType,
                                                                                                                                                                 NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: @(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
                                                                                                                                                              }
                                                                           documentAttributes:nil
                                                                                        error:nil];


 [attributedString beginEditing];

   //Hack for italic/skew effect to custom fonts
 [attributedString enumerateAttribute:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName inRange:NSMakeRange(0, attributedString.length) options:0 usingBlock:^(id value, NSRange range, BOOL *stop) {

    if (value) {

        NSMutableParagraphStyle *myStyle = (NSMutableParagraphStyle *)value;

        if (myStyle.minimumLineHeight == 99) {
            [myStyle setMinimumLineHeight:0];
            [attributedString addAttribute:NSObliquenessAttributeName
                                     value:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.30] range:range];
        }

    }
}];

     //Hack for bold effect.
 [attributedString enumerateAttribute:NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName inRange:NSMakeRange(0, attributedString.length) options:0 usingBlock:^(id value, NSRange range, BOOL *stop) {

     if (value) {

        [attributedString addAttribute:NSStrokeWidthAttributeName
                                                 value:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:-3.0] range:range];

        [attributedString addAttribute:NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName
                                 value:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0] range:range];
      }

}];


[attributedString endEditing];

return attributedString;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try with System fonts just to rule out the possibility that your custom fonts are not added to the project properly.

I once had the same issue but with labels.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6631292/custom-font-in-ios-not-working#10430626) solved it for me. Maybe this helps you.

**Edit:**

Found a very nice article on [how to add custom fonts](http://codewithchris.com/common-mistakes-with-adding-custom-fonts-to-your-ios-app/) to iOS app

Comment: Did this solution Work for you?

Comment: I gave up-vote for reason for the problem. But unfortunately that doesn't give solution to my problem!