# Custom UINavigationBar Font not displaying

Tags: iphone, xcode, uinavigationbar, uifont

My custom TrueType font file that I brought into Xcode is not displaying correctly in the UINavigationBar. Instead of displaying the custom font, it displays the System font (Helvetica Bold).

**RootViewController.m**

```
self.title = @"Library";
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:
     [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
      [UIColor whiteColor], UITextAttributeTextColor,
      [UIFont fontWithName:@"adellebasic_bold.ttf" size:20.0], UITextAttributeFont,nil]];
```

I have also made sure that I copied it into Xcode correctly and I declared it under `UIAppFonts` in the `Info.plist` file. Also note that the code works if I set it to a UIFont that is included in the iPhone SDK but not a custom font brought in.

Does anyone have the slightest idea for what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
    NSMutableDictionary *titleBarAttributes = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary: [[UINavigationBar appearance] titleTextAttributes]];

    [titleBarAttributes setValue:[UIFont fontWithName:@"adellebasic_bold" size:25.0f] forKey:UITextAttributeFont];

    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setTitleTextAttributes:titleBarAttributes];

    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setTitleVerticalPositionAdjustment:4.0f forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

actually the font file name and the font name are two different things.
Check This: [iOS: How can i set a non system font family, style, size of UILabel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6747325/ios-how-can-i-set-a-non-system-font-family-style-size-of-uilabel) .

Try this name "Adelle Basic Bold".