# Changing UINavigationBar font in Swift

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, view, swift, uinavigationbar

I have a `UINavigationBar` with a title in the middle. I have added a custom font ("`Comic_Andy.ttf`") to my app (I have checked `info.plist` to make sure it's listed, and I have checked the `Copy Bundle Resources` to make sure it has been added), and I would like the title of the `UINavigationBar` to be displayed in that font. From what I can gather it seems as though I'm supposed to use this in my `ViewController`:

```
myNavigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Comic_Andy", size: 22)]
```

I placed that method in the `viewDidLoad` function of the `ViewController`. 
 I have also tried this in the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` function of the `AppDelegate`:

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Comic_Andy", size: 22)]
```

I am programming in Swift, in XCode 6 Beta 6. Many resources regarding this task have mentioned using a method called `setTitleTextAttributes`, which is nowhere to be seen. I can't figure it out for the life of me - I've probably spent close to 3 hours on it by now - I have checked every StackOverflow answer, every website, so please do not mark this as a duplicate. 
 Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it took me the whole day, but I got it. My first problem was I didn't even have a NavigationController, so once I got that all sorted out [this is what finally fixed it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5941601/certain-fonts-not-showing-up). Turns out you call the font like this: `Comic Andy` instead of `Comic_Andy`. EVEN THOUGH the font is referred to throughout the entire package as Comic_Andy, and the file is named Comic_Andy, you still use Comic Andy.

Comment: the font name and the file name are different! i've been there

Answer (score 21):

Instead of using myNavigationBar, try navigationController.navigationBar in the ViewController viewDidLoad function.  It worked for me.

```
navigationController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Comic_Andy", size: 22)]
```

If this doesn't work, try using the .ttf suffix.

```
navigationController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Comic_Andy.ttf", size: 22)]
```

Good luck!

Comment: You should post this as an answer.

Answer (score 7):

Can also be done for all NavigationBars with `UINavigationBar.appearance()`.

`UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: Font.mediumFontName, size: 20)!]`